# HTML5 localStorage & Same origin policy: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't

Tags: php, javascript, html, local-storage

I have a server that hosts some .html files (actually all .php, but client only sees html). When the user enters page1.html there's a button to go to page2.html. This button has href="page2.html" and rel="external". The same is true for the 4 other pages.

My localStorage stays between page 1,2 and 3 but not page 4 and 5. Also, if inside a page a popup is opened (I use jquery mobile's popup) any javascript that runs while the popup is opens I always get undefined values for localstorage entries. Google Chrome's element inspector-->resources shows the values while the popup is open, but javascript alerts give undefined.

So: what could cause this? I'm pretty the "[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" applies (all start with http://www.example.com/) but something must cause the other pages to not have the localStorage.

Here's php code that most of my pages start with:

```
<?php
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['userid']);
echo "<script>localStorage.userid = $userid;</script>";

$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['keyword']);
echo "<script>localStorage.keyword = $keyword;</script>";
?>
```

and then I also set the button that goes the next page's its href to include the same php query string so the next page gets the same variables. Of course this would not be necessary if localStorage just worked properly and i could fetch the values from their (and do something with them later on). I use google Chrome's element inspector to see what each page has in the local storage.

Comment: While it seems like a fairly good description, you may want to show how you're getting and setting the values with `localStorage`. I don't know if that would help solve the problem, but it wouldn't hurt

Comment: you're not set up for subdomains are you?

Comment: @ben336 "`(all start with http://www.example.com/)`" would make me think "no", but a good question nonetheless

Comment: if its something like `http://www.example.com/blog/post.html` that could be mapped to blog.example.com

Comment: @ben336 Right, but the browser doesn't know and doesn't care. `localStorage` is all on the client side, and what it sees is what it deals with

Answer (score 2):

I was misusing the combination of phph and localStorage. I sometimes typed the following (omitting the php echo):

localStorage.keyword = $keyword;

but it should have been in quotes:

localStorage.keyword = '$keyword';

So that explains the random behaviour in some pages having only undefined entries.